# PyGame - How to get an image in the center of the screen

Tags: python, pygame

```
# MENU
def gameMenu():
intro = True
while(intro == True):
    win.fill((0,0,0))
    iPATH = f"{PATH}/assets/textures/titleScreen/buttons"
    win.blit(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(f"{iPATH}/startSelected.png")), (screenSize/2,500))
    iPATH = f"{PATH}/assets/textu
    win.blit(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(f"{iPATH}/Logo.png")), (screenSize/2,50))
    pygame.display.update()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    if keys[selectButton]:
        print("clicked z")
        break
    elif keys[backButton]:
        print("clicked x")
    else:
        pass
```

screenSize = 800 btw
So I already tried to divide it by 2 as you can see but it appears like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S9VU.jpg

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You made a simple mathematical mistake. If your screen size is 800 and you divide it by 2, you obtain 400. Therefore, with an image width of, say, 100 pixels, you'll be covering pixels 400 to 500, thus having an skew towards the right.

If you want to truly center your image, you need to account for half its width. Therefore, you calculation to obtain the top left x coordinate should look like:

```
x_centered = screen_width / 2 - image_width / 2
y_centered = screen_height / 2 - image_height / 2 #similarly..
```

Adapting to the specifics of your current project should be rather straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, by convention, you should name your screen `Surface` simply `screen`.

Then, you're loading the image files over and over again in the `while` loop. Just load it once.

It's also good to (almost) always use [`convert`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) after loading an image so the `Surface` will have the same pixel format as the screen.

Finally, in pygame, you should use the [`Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) class for (almost) everything related to drawing/positioning.

Here you can see how easy it is to center something using the `Rect` class. I also reordered your loop to follow the classic input/update/draw convention and removed the second image for brevity:

```
def gameMenu():

    iPATH = f"{PATH}/assets/textures/titleScreen/buttons"
    logo = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(f"{iPATH}/Logo.png")).convert()

    logo_rect = logo.get_rect(center = screen.get_rect().center)

    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[selectButton]:
            print("clicked z")
            break
        elif keys[backButton]:
            print("clicked x")

        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        screen.blit(logo, logo_rect)
        pygame.display.update()
```